# Many to Many SQL Query

Tags: sql

I have three tables:
Requests, Users and UserRequests.

Requests:
 - ID
 - Submit_ID
 - Assign_ID
 - Completed_ID

User:
 - ID
 - UserName

UserRequest:
 - ID
 - Request_ID
 - User_ID

Each request has a different user than the request was submitted by, assigned to and completed by. I'm trying for the following output:

Request.ID | Username of Assigned | Username of Submitted | Username of Completed

Am I going about this is the wrong way?

Comment: Can you show the query you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't understand the purpose of UserRequest, but your intended output is obtained as follows:

```
SELECT
    r.ID,
    us.UserName,
    ua.UserName,
    uc.UserName
FROM
    Requests r
    JOIN Users us 
    ON r.Submit_ID = us.ID
    JOIN Users ua
    ON r.Assign_ID = ua.ID
    JOIN Users uc
    ON r.Complete_ID = uc.ID
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit of a SQL newb. I thought requests and user had a many to many relationship. As usual, I was over thinking the solution. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you are asking (multiple one-to-many joins) by giving the User table a different alias for each join as follows:

```
SELECT  
    Requests.ID AS `Request.ID`,  
    AssignUser.UserName AS `Username of Assigned`,  
    SubmitUser.UserName AS `Username of Submitted`,  
    CompleteUser.UserName AS `Username of Completed`  
FROM  
    Requests  
JOIN User AS AssignUser ON  
    Requests.Assign_ID = AssignUser.ID  
JOIN User AS SubmitUser ON  
    Requests.Submit_ID = SubmitUser.ID  
JOIN User AS CompleteUser ON  
    Requests.Completed_ID = CompleteUser.ID
```

Note that the back ticks are used above for specifying the column aliases. If you aren't using MySQL, you would probably have to use double-quotes for Oracle (or a different character if you are using a different kind of database).